# Convert array of arrays to array of objects grouped together

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of arrays. How do I convert them to an array of objects grouped together?

```js
var abc = [
  ['apple', 'fruit'], ['banana', 'fruit'], ['grapes', 'fruit'], ['red', 'color'], ['blue', 'color'], ['black', 'color']
]


abc = abc.map(function(item) {
  return {
    value: item[0],
    color: item[1]
  }
})

colors = abc.filter(function(item) {
  return item.color === 'color'
})

fruits = abc.filter(function(item) {
  return item.color === 'fruit'
})

var result = [{
  group: 'color',
  value: colors.map(function(item) {
    return item.value
  })
}, {
  group: 'fruit',
  value: fruits.map(function(item) {
    return item.value
  })
}]

console.log(result)
```

My expected output is:

```
var abc = [
{
    group: 'color',
    value: ['red', 'blue', 'black']
},
{
    group: 'fruit',
    value: ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes']
}]
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

I can use lodash too. Please advise.

Comment: Use reduce, group elements that match the `group` value; by extending object IF already exists, and creating if it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group with lodash by the index and map the values of the other index.

```js
var data = [['apple', 'fruit'], ['banana', 'fruit'], ['grapes', 'fruit'], ['red', 'color'], ['blue', 'color'], ['black', 'color']],
    result = _(data)
        .groupBy(1)
        .map((array, group) => ({ group, value: _.map(array, 0) }))
        .sortBy('group')
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using `reduce` and `map`. `reduce` performs an aggregation by `group` mapped to an array of values. `Object.entries()` and `map` transform this grouping into the desired format as an array of objects.

```js
var abc = [
  ['apple', 'fruit'],
  ['banana', 'fruit'],
  ['grapes', 'fruit'],
  ['red', 'color'],
  ['blue', 'color'],
  ['black', 'color']
];

const result = Object.entries(
    abc.reduce((a, e) => {
      if (!(e[1] in a)) {
        a[e[1]] = [];
      }

      a[e[1]].push(e[0]);
      return a;
    }, {})
  ).map(e => ({group: e[0], value: e[1]}))
;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: IMHO this is cleanest and most "functional" approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method I've described in a comment to your question:

1. you loop through all elements, and create a blank array
2. Inside of your newly created array, you find object matching `group` value
3. If found, you extend the element
4. If not found, you create it

   ```
   abc.reduce((arr, input) => {
     const index = arr.findIndex(i => i.group === input[0])

     return [
       ...(index > -1
         ? [
           ...arr.slice(0, index),
           {
             group: input[0],
             value: [
               ...arr[index].value,
               input[1]
             ]
           },
           ...arr.slice(index + 1)
         ] : [
           ...arr,
           {
             group: input[0],
             value: [ input[1] ]
           }
         ])
     ]
   }, [])
   ```

Comment: IMHO such long ternary operator may be confusing to decrypt, but hey, that's at least different approach

Comment: @Tomas agree, but that's why consistent indentation is the key here

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to do it with an ES6 `Map` as intermediate data structure:

```js
var abc = [['apple', 'fruit'],['banana', 'fruit'],['grapes', 'fruit'],['red', 'color'],['blue', 'color'],['black', 'color']];
    
const groups = new Map(abc.map(a =>[a[1], []]));
abc.forEach(a => groups.get(a[1]).push(a[0]));
const result = Array.from(groups, ([group, values]) =>  ({group, values}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build up a hashtavle to find duplicate descriptors:

```
 const result = [], hash = {};

 for(const [value, group] of abc) {
  if(hash[group]) {
   hash[group].push(value);
  } else {
   result.push({ group, value: (hash[group] = [value]), });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach with single `reduce`

```
var abc = [
  ['apple', 'fruit'],
  ['banana', 'fruit'],
  ['grapes', 'fruit'],
  ['red', 'color'],
  ['blue', 'color'],
  ['black', 'color']
]

var r = abc.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if(prev.findIndex(p => p.group === curr[1]) === -1) {
    prev = prev.concat({group: curr[1], value: []})
  }
  let idx = prev.findIndex(p => p.group === curr[1])
  prev[idx].value.push( curr[0] )
  return prev;
}, [])

console.log(r)
```